# Cómo saber si un valor es numérico

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una validación.
Me devuelven dos cadenas, una de ellas tiene que ser un valor numérico inferior a 10000 y la otra cadena tiene que tener un valor String que no este vacío.

Planteo lo siguiente:

```java
public boolean validar(String val1, String val2) {
    if(!esNum(gpag) && Integer.parseInt(gpag) > 10000 && q.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}
    
public static boolean esNum(String cadena){     
    try{
        if(cadena!= null){
            Integer.parseInt(cadena);
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
         
    }
    return false;
}
```

¿Alguien podría decirme si es correcto o no?

Comment: Buenas, Alejandro, bienvenido al sitio. Una cosa, el método esNum siempre devuelve false. y ¿qué pasa cuando val1 es exactamente igual a 10000?

Comment: Vale el método esNum tenia mal el return, si deja convertirlo obviamente es true. Me equivoque.

Comment: `if(!esNum(val1) && Integer.parseInt(val1) > 10000 && val2.isEmpty()) {`

Comment: La corrección que hice aparte de poner el return a true es negarlo cuando lo compruebo. Entonces mi idea es que si no es numérico, es superior a 10000 y val 2 esta vacío que devuelva verdadero o falso

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta para corregir la errata de esNum. Por otro lado, ten en cuenta que si pones !esEnum, la unión con el resto de condiciones debe ser disyuntiva, es decir no será válido si ((val1 no es un número) o (val1 >= 10000) o val2.isEmpty).  Quizás deberías comprobar también que val2 no sea null antes de hacer val2.isEmpty.

Comment: No afectaría al resto de la línea únicamente se esta negando el método

Comment: Sí, tú estás negando el método, pero creo que la condición total no se corresponde con tu enunciado. Si val1 es un número menor que 10000 y val2 está vacío, ¿qué devuelve tu método validar? true ¿Es correcto ese resultado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes algunos fallos en la lógica:

- esNum siempre devuelve `false`.
- Estás llamando a `Integer.parseInt` dos veces, de manera innecesaria.

Podrías hacer algo como:

```
public static boolean esNumMenorQue(String cadena, int limite){     
    try {
        //da igual que sea null, se lanzará una NFE
        return Integer.parseInt(cadena) < limite;
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
      //no es un número
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: ya pero si no esta convertido en el método validar como compruebo que es un numero superior a 10000 ¿? y que no se repita

Comment: tendrías que validarlo después. Este métdo te podría ahorrar el validar si un string está vacío, ya que si está vacío o o no puede convertirlo, entraría al bloque `catch`

Comment: Estoy un poco liado con eso. El método de validar: si entra en el try, puede convertir el valor a integer si no arroja una excepción. Al ser un método booleano retorna un false (¿Si se retorna el false con el !esNum estoy diciendo que el valor no es numerico verdad? )

Comment: Ahora por otro lado repito dos veces el parseInt para convertir el numero. Como sugieren que haga la validación de que si el numero es mayor a 10000 entre en el if también

Comment: El método que he puesto devuelve true si cadena se puede convertir a un entero y ese entero es menor que `limite`. En otro caso devolverá false.

Comment: Aun habiéndole añadido el return false. ¿Si es numero y es menor que limite devuelve true? Me refiero no hay que negarlo para que de true

Comment: Hay 3 opciones: 1. Se ejecuta sin fallo el bloque `try` y devuelve true (es un int menor que `limite`, 2. Se ejecuta sin fallo el bloque `try` y devuelve false (es un entero NO menor que `limite`). 3. Se lanza un NFE (no es un entero) y devuelve false

Answer (score 0):

Aparte de lo aportado por @pablo-lozano, una pequeña sugerencia adicional.

Siempre que tengas esta estructura en tu código

```
if (cond) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Puedes simplificarla como

```
return cond;
```

Si juntamos esta recomendación con la propuesta de Pablo, el método validar quedaría

```
public boolean validar(String val1, String val2) {
    return esNumMenorQue(val1, 10000) && val2 != null && !val2.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Muy buenas respuestas todos, me habéis ayudado bastante a corregirlo y comprenderlo. Muchas gracias